# How do I display subtotals in cube browser in SSAS 2012 (Sql Server Data Tools)?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, business-intelligence, olap, cube

Apparently this feature was available in previous versions but has now been removed.

What are some alternatives?

Comment: You could try using Excel.  This will let you open a pivot table over an OLAP data source.  It will inherit subtotals from calculations in the cube.

Answer (score 3):

That's right. The cube browser control within SSDT is completely different to the one that used to exist in BIDS2008 or lower. This had me going at first too. The best way i found to get around this was to launch into excel, which can be done from the cube browser tab.

I believe it even creates a temporary connection file for you too so you don't have to create that yourself. Then all you need to do is create a pivot table to display the data how you want.